# How to Add field with default value, without triggering full rewrite of table?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-migrations

I want to add new field in existing model

**current Model**

```
class InfoModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
```

**New Model**
where I want to add new field `count`

```
class InfoModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

this model creates following migration file

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('info', '0001_auto_20220303_1048'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='infomodel',
            name='count',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=0),
        ),
    ]
```

but If I migrate using above migration file it will trigger full table overwrite for existing rows. how can I avoid it?

I tried suggestion from documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/migration-operations/#addfield not sure, If I did it correctly by creating 2 migrations file because after second migration it was still filling default value for existing rows. I want only new entry into model should have default value, existing rows not required.

Comment: It's a non-nullable column, you have to insert values for existing rows they can't contain null

Answer (score 0):

add null=True or assign a value to existing instances of InfoModel